# I want to exponentiate log e outcome varaible for my generalised linear regression model in the gtsummary package

Tags: gtsummary

I want to exponentiate my loge outcome variables and include them in my regression table using the tbl_regression. see below: can someone help me with how to exponentiate the log(HB) coefficient to include in the regression table.

```
*t2 <-
  lm(log(hgb)~ treatment, endline1) %>%
     tbl_regression(exponentiate = FALSE*.
```

regards
Mamadou

Comment: `log(hgb)` is your model outcome and does not have a coefficient.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the quick response. what if I want to exponentiate the exposure variables see below:   *mu <-
  lm(log(iron)~ treatment + log(erythroferrone)+ log(epo)+ log(crp)+ log(hepciden), data=endline1) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)%>%
     as_gt()
theme_gtsummary_journal(journal = "nejm")*

I have this error after running the model.

*Error in tidy_and_attach(., tidy_fun = tidy_fun, conf.int = conf.int,  : 
  `exponentiate = TRUE` is not valid for this type of model.*